# Connecting to remote server failed using WinRM from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm

I am trying to run powershell code from my computer to vm on my computer, but i keep getting this error:

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
>   The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication
>   scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not
>   joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the
>   destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration
>   setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers
>   in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more
>   information about that by running the following command: winrm help
>   config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic.

my code:

```
  string runasUsername = @"\aaa";
    string runasPassword = "aaa";
    SecureString ssRunasPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char x in runasPassword)
        ssRunasPassword.AppendChar(x);
    PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(runasUsername, ssRunasPassword);

    var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://10.0.5.35/PowerShell"),
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",credentials);
    connInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

    var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo);


    var domainName = "domainName.COM";
    var password = "ActiveDirectoryPassword1234";
    var ssPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
        ssPassword.AppendChar(c);


    var command = new Command("New-Mailbox");

    command.Parameters.Add("FirstName", firstName);
    command.Parameters.Add("LastName", lastName);
    command.Parameters.Add("Password", ssPassword);
    command.Parameters.Add("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", false);
    command.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", "NeumontStudents");

    runspace.Open(); <--//error here
    var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.Add(command);


    var results = pipeline.Invoke();

    runspace.Dispose();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to check things mentioned in error message?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the client and the remote machine aren't *on the same domain*, you have one of two options:

- use HTTPS as a transport protocol
- add the remote machine to the list of trusted hosts on the client

In order to [configure WinRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to use HTTPS, open up a PowerShell console *as administrator* on both machines and run:

```
winrm quickconfig -transport:https
```

and open port 5986 on the firewall:

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "WinRM over HTTPS"
```

Alternatively, you can add the remote machine as trusted host *on the client* by running:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="10.0.5.35"}
```

Comment: yup it is , i get this:"WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine."

Comment: @woolford are the client and server on the same domain?

Comment: There's a way to use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate: http://www.jayway.com/2011/11/21/winrm-w-self-signed-certificate-in-4-steps/

Comment: OK, the winrm command only works if you remove the single quotes. (It still didn't solve the problem for me).

Comment: The first command will not run as easily as it seems. The following link will tell you how to make it run: https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/devops/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https-manually

Comment: I am getting `Error: Invalid use of command line` when running `winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="<my_host_ip>"}`.

Comment: Same ``'Invalid use'`` error for me, adding single quotes fixed it ``winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="10.0.5.35"}'``

Comment: It works: 
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'machineA,machineB'

Answer (score 4):

Setting this up on a new client, I had to:

1. Run PowerShell as administrator
2. Enable WinRM by running this command and answering yes to the prompt:

   ```
   winrm quickconfig
   ```
3. Add the host to my trusted hosts (where `1.2.3.4` is the host's IP address):

   ```
   Set-Item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value 1.2.3.4 -Concatenate
   ```

Comment: >"Enable WinRM by running this command and answering yes to the prompt:
winrm quickconfig"


Note you have to run this command on the client as well as server computers, else the next command will fail.

Answer (score 2):

have you enabled winrm on both machines?
try running `winrm quickconfig` on each machine to ensure remote connectivity is enabled.

Comment: yup it is , i get this:"WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine."

Comment: Try using CredSSP authentication. Look at the steps in my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336336/running-batch-file-on-remote-computers-using-powershell-2-0/15336790#15336790

Comment: CredSSP is used to allow the remote machine to pass on the client's credentials when connecting to other services (i.e. a [second-hop](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx)). The problem in this case is that the client and the server aren't on the same domain.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought this would resolve the cross domain authentication since the standard authentication is not working.