# Error while running Azure runbook which executes PowerShell command on Virtual Machine

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, powershell-remoting, runbook

I am trying to execute this code in runbook, using "Invoke-Command" to connect to VM.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

    "Logging in to Azure"
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    # Use the subscription that this Automation account is in
    $null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $servicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID
    Get-AzureRmVM | Select Name
    $dcred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'myvm1creds'
    Write-Output $DomainCred
    $opts = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
    Invoke-Command -Computername 'myVM1' -Credential $dcred -ScriptBlock {Get-Process} -SessionOption $opts
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    } 
}
```

Getting the below error:

***[myVM1] Connecting to remote server myVM1 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the 
request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, 
then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. 
Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You 
can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (myVM1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionStateBroken***

Any idea what have to be done to run powershell script via runbook on Azure Virtual Machines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote server failed using WinRM from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010091/connecting-to-remote-server-failed-using-winrm-from-powershell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote server failed using WinRM from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010091/connecting-to-remote-server-failed-using-winrm-from-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure runbook, we can't use transport HTTP to connect Azure VMs, because Azure runbook can't add trust host, so we need use **HTTPS** to connect Azure VMs.

Here are my steps:
1.Create a self-signed certificate.

Use `makecert.exe` to create it.

2.Config Winrm listen on **HTTPS**, run this script in CMD:

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Port="5986" ;Hostname="jasonvm" ;CertificateThumbprint="98941E137CDF9553CCB0C28D5814EB9EDB1AC87D"}
```

3.Add **port 5986** in Azure NSG inbound rules and windows firewall inbound rules.
4.we can use this runbook to connect Azure VM:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 


    $null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $servicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID
    Get-AzureRmVM | Select Name
    $dcred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'jasonvm'
    Write-Output $DomainCred
    $opts = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'https://52.185.148.177:5986' -Credential $dcred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
    Invoke-Command -Session $opts -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}

}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using "-ConnectionUri 'https://52.185.148.177:5986'" can we get it by using VM Name? I tried but didnt work out for me.