# Troubleshooting WinRM for Hyper-V WorkGroup Config

Tags: hyper-v, wsman

I have Hyper-V Core deployed on 2019.  I followed the instructions from a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUwwmwReV2o) to enable management without a domain but for some reason it has recently stopped working with the error:

[image]

Those instructions from the youtube video can be summarized by

1. Set Network Category to private on Both Computers
2. Enable ICMP Ping to the Hyper V server
3. Enable Remote Management option on Hyper V
4. Enable WinRM with quickconfig
5. Add computers to Trusted Hosts
6. Save your credentials with CMDKey.

I have checked the trustedhosts on both the Server and my Computer and all seems good.  Additionally I have verified I can ping both with both the Computer name and the IP successfully

HyperV Server (added both the computer name adn IP address in trying to troubleshoot)

```
get-item  wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts
WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   192.168.1.184,My-pc
```

My Computer

```
get-item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts
WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   hyperv_01
```

Network Category is still set to Private as verified by "Get-netConnectionProfile" and authentication works as when I RDP to the HyperV Server it just connects without prompting for password.  Additionally when I launch Server Manager on my computer to the Hyper V computer it all works just fine.

I am at a loss on how to troubleshoot this or get to the bottom of why I can not connect to hyperV Manger on my server, what further troubleshooting should I be looking at?

Comment: Hi, for troubleshooting you should check your Event Viewer "Microsoft  > Windows > Windows Remote Management". Maybe this Post can help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010091/connecting-to-remote-server-failed-using-winrm-from-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Compare patch level both on host and the client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).