# Using Invoke-WmiMethod to run an executable on a remote machine as a particular user

Tags: powershell, impersonation

As part of some deployment automation, I am trying to run an executable on a remote machine using powershell. The excutable needs to run as a particular user so that it can connect to the appropriate database to do its work.

For example, the Powershell script is running on Machine1 as user "Org\TFSUser". It needs to run the executable on Machine2 as the "Devel\BuildServices" user. I am trying to use the Invoke-WmiMethod commandlet to start the executable on the remote server as shown below. This seems to work in that it runs the executable on the remote machine but using the Anonymous user login. The error I see in the logs is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`

```
$username = "devel\BuildServices"
$password = cat Deploy\SecurePasswords\PasswordForBuildServicesAsSecureString.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("C:\TeamCityDeployments\Importer\Importer.exe -pFile:C:\TeamCityDeployments\Importer\alphaParams.txt >> importer.log") -ComputerName "Machine2.devel" -Impersonation 3 -EnableAllPrivileges -Credential $cred
```

To build up the credential object with password without prompting, I am using the secure strings as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password).

In the Invoke-WmiMethod, I am supplying the parameter "-Impersonation 3" as specified [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849748.aspx). My understanding was that this would start the remote process while impersonating the user credentials that I am passing in.

Can anyone tell me how to run the executable on a remote machine using the credentials of a specific user.

Comment: I haven't really used the Invoke-WmiMethod before, it may well be the right way of achieving what you want, but I think you can also do that using (New-PSSession/Enter-PSSession) or Invoke-Command as they both take credential when invoking them.

Comment: Tried to use the Invoke-Command as well as New-PSession commmand. Doesn't make any difference, I still keep getting the same Anonymous Logon error.

Comment: Did you specify the authentication method when calling Invoke-Command? You'll need to use CredSSP as you seem to have the double-hop authentication issue.

Check my answer for this question to see how to setup and use CredSSP, it's fairly simple.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336336/running-batch-file-on-remote-computers-using-powershell-2-0/15336790#15336790

Comment: Yup. That was it. Is working now. You should move the comments above into an answer so I can accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `New-PSSession` and `Invoke-Command` with the `CredSSP` authentication as you seem to have the double-hop authentication issue.

Check my answer to the question below to see how to setup and use CredSSP, it's fairly simple.

[Running batch file on Remote Computers using PowerShell 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336336/running-batch-file-on-remote-computers-using-powershell-2-0/15336790#15336790)

Comment: btw (may be is not an issue here), but New-PSSession requires WinRM service, while WMI is started almost instantly.