# powershell - Invoke-Command : The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows PowerShell script file

Tags: powershell

I have a re-usable script that I've been using with success calling a remote ps1 file but now I'm trying to call a remote batch file and I get the following error message -

```
Invoke-Command : The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows
PowerShell script file. Enter the path to a file with a .ps1 file name
extension and try the command again.
```

This is the script -

```
#Admin Account 
$AdminUser = "domain\svc_account" 
$Password = Get-Content D:\scripts\pass\crd-appacct.txt | convertto-securestring
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminUser, $Password 
$FileName = "runme.bat"
$ItemLocation = "D:\path\to\bat\"

#Invoke Script Remotely
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername -filepath "$ItemLocation$FileName" -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: `.bat` file located on local computer and you want to invoke it on remote computer?

Comment: @PetSerAl the bat file is remote.

Comment: Use `-ScriptBlock` instead of `-FilePath`: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& "$using:ItemLocation$using:FileName"} ...`.

Comment: @PetSerAl submit as a solution and I'll accept I actually googled it and found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336336/running-batch-file-on-remote-computers-using-powershell-2-0 which solved it.  Exactly what you were saying :)

Comment: Just curious, but why are you running a batch file from within PowerShell when PowerShell can probably do whatever the batch file does, and do it better?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - I'm not creating the script it's being supplied to me to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `-ScriptBlock` parameter instead of `-FilePath`:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername -ScriptBlock {& "$using:ItemLocation$using:FileName"} -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $Credential
```

Or if you are using PowerShell v2, which does not have `$using:VariableName` syntax:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername -ScriptBlock {param($ItemLocation,$FileName) & "$ItemLocation$FileName"} -ArgumentList $ItemLocation,$FileName -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $Credential
```