# How to run the batch file on the computer from another computer?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, remote-access, remote-server

I have computers connected in LAN. From one PC say A I want to run the batch file stored in computer B. I don't want to use any resources of A. That batch file contains resource sensitive process. So the resource of B should only used. The batch file should be run on B but initiated from A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running batch file on Remote Computers using PowerShell 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336336/running-batch-file-on-remote-computers-using-powershell-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

Through batch file you can use WMIC or SCHTASKS:

1) [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html):

```
SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /create /tn "On demand demo" /tr "C:\some.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /run /TN "On demand demo"
```

2) [WMIC](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) (wmic will return the pid of the started process)

```
WMIC /NODE remote_machine /user user /password password process call create "c:\some.bat","c:\exec_dir"
```

Comment: I tried SCHTASKS. But this run the process on machine A. Which I dont want because I want to run 14 such batch file on 14 machines. I want them to run on the respective machines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough privilegies and WinRM configured.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'RemotePCName' -ScriptBlock { 'c:\temp\script.bat' } -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849719.aspx) and create a [PSSession](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849717.aspx)

And it looks like:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ComputerB"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { ./P:\Path\to\bat.bat  }
$session | Remove-Session
```

That should be what you need.
If you have any output in your batch file you can use

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ComputerB"
$output = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { ./P:\Path\to\bat.bat  }
$session | Remove-Session
```

If you need any $vars inside the ScriptBlock you can use:

```
$examplePath = "P:\Path\to"
$exampleFile = "mySCript.bat"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ComputerB"
$output = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { ./$args[0] + "\" + $args[1]  } -ArgumentList $examplePath, $exampleFile
$session | Remove-Session
```

Comment: Remove-Session doesn't exists; you should use Remove-PSSession (tested on Win Serv 2019)